# CodeIgniter form validation, re-populating dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, dynamic, validation

I've got a form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
</form>
<button id="add">Add extra field</button>
```

And there is a possibility to add more inputs which I've handled with Javascript / jQuery:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('form').append('<input type="text" name="name[]">');
}
```

Everything here works fine. When I submit the form and I echo the data with `echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->input->post(),TRUE).'</pre>';` I'm getting everything.

And I'm using the form validation class, so if something fails I'd like to hold the values by using the `set_value` function. Then the form looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?=set_value('name[]');?>">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?=set_value('name[]');?>">
</form>
<button id="add">Add extra field</button>
```

But... the dynamically added inputs aren't there because they're added by Javascript. The question is: how to "hold" the dynamically added inputs and there values with CodeIgniter after de form validation failed?

Searched around but couldn't find anything :(

Comment: can you echo the forms data submitted to the controller to check the presence of all the dynamically fields added to view.

Comment: Yes, when I run `echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->input->post(),TRUE).'</pre>';` I'm getting everything.

Comment: one more thing is this(dynamic) field getting validated on server-side? Can you try something like this `value="<?php echo set_value('name[]',$_POST['name[]']);?>"`

Comment: Yes, but by the array name so it doesn't matter if there're just 2 or 100 or them. What you're suggesting doesn't solve the problem because the dynamically added fields aren't there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a provision of index on each of your form element.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name[1]">
    <input type="text" name="name[2]">
</form>
```

So, your JS becomes like,

```
counter = 3;
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('form').append('<input type="text" name="name['+counter+']">');
    counter++;
}
```

Now, if your validation fails, you have to add condition like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        foreach($this->input->post('name') as $ind=>$item)
        {
    ?>
        <input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $ind ?>]" 
                         value="<?=set_value('name[".$ind ."]');?>">
    <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        <input type="text" name="name[1]">
        <input type="text" name="name[2]">
    <?php
    }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: I've updated my question, I think you misunderstood me. But thanks for your reply!

Comment: A little bit hacky but I think it's gone a work! Thank you! I'll dig into it and I'll post the solution in my case. If I look at this I don't think I've to specify a index in the array name.

Comment: @hsuk and Roy, is this the only to do this *exact* solution? Because I have dynamic fields created by JS and I do re-creation with PHP (since they are deleted in the DOM), so I have redundant code with the JS-creation and PHP re-creation. Do y'all know a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how I did it:

**The Controller**

```
<?php
$data['some_data'] = ''; // Some data from the database to send to the view
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    // Posted?
    if($this->input->post())
    {
        // Merge the submitted data with the current data
        $data = array_merge($this->input->post(),$data);
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->load->view('view',$data);
}
else
{
    // Code after validation was successfull
}
```

**The view**

```
<? if(isset($name)): // Name set? ?>
    <? foreach($name as $item): // Loop through all previous posted items ?>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?=set_value('name[]'); // Set it's value with the regular set_value function  ?>">
    <? endforeach; ?>
<? else: ?>
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
<? endif; ?>
```

This way it isn't hacky with controller stuff in the view and it works perfectly!

@hsuk, thanks!